# XSLT fn:tokenize ignore leading and trailing spaces

Tags: xslt

Simple date string needs to be tokenized. I'am using this sample xslt code:

```
fn:tokenize(date, '[ .\s]+')
```

All variants of bad date format (i.e. "10.10.2020", "10. 10 .2020", "10 .  10. 2020") are tokenized ok using the function above, except if there's a leading space present (i.e. " 10.10.2020"). If leading space is present, first element is then tokenized as " " blank space.

Is there an option to ignore these leading spaces as well so no matter how bad the format is, only delimiter "." means another token and all spaces are stripped as well?

Comment: Can't you just use `tokenize(normalize-space(date), '\.')`? Or use `tokenize(replace(date, '^\s+|\s+$'), '[ .\s]+')`.

Comment: I tried the fist option as you suggested, but it still leaves some spaces (22-) (-6-) (-2018) with each element. I just replaced spaces with "-" to illustrate situation. Then I simply updated my code with normalize-space and that one works ok. I posted also the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The right solution seems to be:

```
fn:tokenize(normalize-space(date, '[ .\s]+')
```